# Get reference to the Master Page from the base class of content pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a few content pages that inherit from BasePage and use a Master Page.

From the BasePage.cs file, I need to call a method defined in the Master Page.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
    var masterPage = ((MasterPageType)Master);
or to access the function:
    ((MasterPageType)Master).SomeFunction();
```

You might have to set the master page file in your base page programmatically as well.  We do it in the OnPreInit function.

```
this.MasterPageFile = "~/masterPage.master";
```

Comment: The content pages have the following:
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Shared/MyMaster.master" %>

They don't have the TypeName attribute set. I assume I have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Page.Master
```

You can than cast that property to your specific masterpage type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Strongly Typed Master Pages](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/419.aspx). Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728168/finding-controls-inside-nested-master-pages/728215#728215).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a property given below to enable header in Master Page:

Master Page Code:

```
Public Property EnablePageHeader() As Boolean
    Get
        If ViewState("EnablePageHeader") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("EnablePageHeader") = True
        End If
        Return DirectCast(ViewState("EnablePageHeader"), Boolean)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        ViewState("EnablePageHeader") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Now if you want to call this Property from any other base class or any other page then you can write code as follow:

DirectCast(Master, DefaultMaster).EnablePageHeader = False

Hope similar is the case of Methods too.

Please respond if the code above helped you are if there is any mistake in it.

Thanks,

Comment: Is DefaultMaster the value of TypeName? If so, please see my comment for Kevin earlier.