# Find Control on MasterPage returns nulll

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to access a ModalPopupExtender control and it allways is returning null or object set not set to an intance of an object. I've tried master.Page.FindControl("") and master.FindControl("") and im still not getting the result

```
MasterPage master = Page.Master as MasterPage;
AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender popup = master.Page.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender2") as AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender;
```

Updated: Cannot change the text of my labels in master page

```
MasterPage master = Page.Master;
AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender popup1 = master.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1") as AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender;
Label lblMessage = master.FindControl("lblMessage") as Label;
lblMessage.Text = msg;
Literal ltrlMessage = master.FindControl("ltrlMessage") as Literal;
ltrlMessage.Text = msg;

Label MessageStatus = master.FindControl("lblMessageStatus") as Label;
MessageStatus.Text = msgStatus;        
popup1.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
    MasterPage master = Page.Master;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728215/37064) answer. You can have a [strongly typed master page](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/419.aspx), so you don't have to find and then cast the control. The control on the master would be publicly accessible, and the page would know the type of the master page and have it accessible.

**EDIT:**

> the control is not public

Assuming you've set the Master property in your page directive:

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.master" ...
```

Odds are, you probably don't need to actually get to the control. Rather, you need to set something in the master page. I'd just use an internal method to do what you need to do:

```
public partial class MyMaster: MasterPage
{
    internal void SetTheFoo(string foo)
    {
        this.WhateverControl.Text = foo;
    }

    //etc...
}
```

Then, from your page, just call it:

```
Master.SetTheFoo("Foo");
```

If you still need to get to the control, then in your master page, you could add a public property exposing your modal popup extender.

```
public AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender MyModalPopup
{
    get { return this.TheNonPublicModalPopupExtenderControl; }

}
```

Comment: I've updated my code and I can access the PopupExtender but I can't change the label text property do you know how I can change the text to my messages

Answer (score 0):

If your page is a child of your master page

try this:

```
AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender popup = (AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)Page.Master.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender2");
```

Regards