# Master Page load not being called

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

```
 public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name != "") //if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart cart = new BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart();
                int count = cart.getNoOfProducts(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                Label lblCart = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblCartNo");
                lblCart.Text = " (" + count + ")";
            }
        }
    }
```

I placed a breakpoint and this code is never called (even without the if statement), also I was not able to find the label which is located in the master page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for Page_Load to be called, make sure that in your MasterPage.aspx have AutoEventWireup="true":

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Mysite.Website.Templates.MasterPages.Site" %>
```

Make sure that MasterPage.aspx Inherits attribute matches your code-behind namespace and class name, as well as your .designer.cs namespace and class.

If the aspx and code-behind files all are wired up correctly, then you should be able to remove the FindControl statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just realised this is missing from my masterpage. However I am not able to manually input it correctly.

Comment: what should i enter in the Inherits= ?

Comment: Inherits should contain the fully qualified classname. Go to your code-behind .cs file. Combine that namespace with your classname, and set your Inherits attribute to that string. In my example the namespace is "Mysite.Website.Templates" and class name is "Site". If that seems confusing, then try adding a new MasterPage and move all markup + codebehind. Visual Studio should wireup the files correctly for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Page_Load event for your master page should definitely be firing.  Not sure why your breakpoint isn't being hit, but to double check, I'd recommend trying something a bit more brute force to make absolutely sure that the method is definitely not being called:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Page_Load");
    Response.End();
}
```

Your label may not be found due to the way controls are nested as Master.FindControl won't work if the control resides inside another control.  I'd recommend checking out "[Finding controls inside of nested master pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728168/finding-controls-inside-nested-master-pages/728199#728199)" which has a useful helper method that can be used to search for controls recursively.